# Iterating over queryset with one to many related fields in views

Tags: django-views

Given model:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

How can I iterate over related values in views. Maybe I'm missing something or doing something wrong but I want to query:

```
reporters=Reporter.objects.prefetch_related('article_set').all()
```

and then iterate:

```
views.py
some_list=[]
for reporter in reporters:
    some_list.append(reporter.first_name)
         for article in 'article_set'
              some_list.append(article.headline)
```

but for some reasons i'm getting error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute
```

I know that article_set is a string but how to iterate over related model ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py

```
some_list = []
reporters = Reporter.objects.all()
for reporter in reporters:
    for article in reporter.article_set.all():
        some_list.append(aricle.headline)
```

Maybe something like this.

Comment: Yes , it's working fine. You saved me a tons of hour trying to figure it out. Thanks